# Is there an equivalent to gl_LocalInvocationIndex in a HLSL compute shader?

Tags: hlsl, compute-shader

Or do I need to calculate this myself?  I can't find a reference for built in global variables in HLSL compute shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be SV_GroupIndex, which, as described in msdn is :

> The "flattened" index of a compute shader thread within a thread group, which turns the multi-dimensional SV_GroupThreadID into a 1D value. SV_GroupIndex varies from 0 to (numthreadsX * numthreadsY * numThreadsZ) – 1.

```
SV_GroupIndex = SV_GroupThreadID.z*dimx*dimy + 
                  SV_GroupThreadID.y*dimx + 
                  SV_GroupThreadID.x
```

[MSDN Documentation Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471569(v=vs.85).aspx)